# How to call method under @Before annotation

Tags: java, exception, selenium, junit, automated-tests

Have troubles with calling method from another class under @Before junit annotation.

Class1:

```
public class welcomePageTests extends SystemLogin {
    @Page
    system system;
    protected TestHarness getTestHarness() {
    return TestHarness.getInstance();        }
        private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(welcomePageTests.class);

    @Before
    loggingToSystem();

    @Test
    public void shouldVerifyPageLayoutAfterFirstRunAndLayoutConsistency() throws Exception {
    clickOnByLocator(welcome.homeButton);
    assertThatIsDisplayedByLocator(welcome.usersButton);
    mainPageLayout.assertMainPageElements(welcome);
    clickOnByLocator(welcome.usersButton);
    mainPageLayout.assertMainPageElements(welcome);
    clickOnByLocator(welcome.loginButton);
    mainPageLayout.assertMainPageElements(welcome);
}
```

Class2:

```
public class SystemLogin extends HelperMethods {
    protected TestHarness getTestHarness() {
        return TestHarness.getInstance();
    }
    @Page
    system system;

        public void loggingToSystem() throws InterruptedException {
        goTo(PageRunner.class);
        getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        system.userLogin.text("mr");
        system.password.text("password");
        system.signInbutton.click();
    }
}
```

Problem is that I can't call directly loggingToSystem method under @Before annotation (while for eg. under @Test annotation works fine).

Getting invalid method declaration error

Tried as well like that:

```
@Before
public void loggingToSystem() {return loggingToSystem();}
```

but in that case getting error that can't return value from method with void result type.

Anyone know what causes the issue and could give me ready solution ?

Answer (score 1):

What is the `loggingToPanda()` return type?

A method with `void` return type means, it will not return any thing. if `loggingToPanda()` method also has `void` return type, then change your code like:

```
@Before
public void loggingToPanda() {
                loggingToPanda();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One second after posted about it have realised that made mistake  :)
This is solution:

```
@Before
public void setup() throws InterruptedException {
    loggingToPanda();
}
```